# How to use FFTW DLL import library .lib as a static .lib in my project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, static-libraries, fftw

I've knowledge of C++ and compiling small plug-ins (always based on a similar and laid out workflow). Though currently I need to compile the latest version of FFTW into a static library (or get it from the compiled version which should supposedly be a lot easier) and it's giving me an insanely hard time. Probably because I don't know the ins and outs of compiling. *As a note I'm working on Windows with Visual Studio.*

Since I really want to know how this should work I'm asking the question here.

Basically I need a static .lib of fftw3f library on Windows that I can include in another Visual Studio project.

The first I did was download the 64 bit dll's of FFTW from the website (hoping I could use this).
http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html

Then I've done the accompanying step they stated, that is:
Run the following in lib.exe.

```
 lib /def:libfftw3-3.def
 lib /def:libfftw3f-3.def
 lib /def:libfftw3l-3.def
```

I've done this as well and got a .lib file that I could use in my project correctly. I've been able to compile my project, yet the output build apparently dynamically linked to the library instead of including it as a static library.

I'm compiling my project to .dll but require the fftw3f library to be statically included in my output.

Using `lib.exe /list libfftw3f-3.lib` I was able to find out that the lib file was referencing the libfftw3f-3.dll.

According to my google results this would mean the .lib file that I created is a **DLL import library** instead of **static library**.

It's hard to figure out how to phrase my question because I'm not sure what the terminology is and what's going on *behind the scenes*. I guess:

- How can I use the libfftw3f-3.lib file created from lib.exe as a static library in my own project. So that it is included in my output .dll instead of dynamically linked?

*Based on what I learn from comments/answers I'll be happy to update/edit/rephrase my question to make more sense for most other users as I'm likely way of with the terminology*

Comment: Did you figure out how to statically link FFTW?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot expect to convert a DLL into a static library.

In order to create a static library you need to re-compile the library from its source code, with an output target that is a static library. If you cannot obtain the source code, then your goal cannot be achieved.