# How do I statically link FFTW on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, linker, static-linking

During the setup of my project - when I knew even less than I do now about cmake - I was [trying my hardest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744205/how-do-you-link-fftw-using-cmake-on-windows) to link the FFTW library.

`C:\\path\\to\\fftw-3.3.5-dll64` contains the `.h` files, `.lib` files (generated from `.def` files) and  `.dll` files.

What I ended up doing was adding these links to my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(${TargetName} PRIVATE main.cpp)
target_include_directories(${TargetName} PRIVATE "C:\\path\\to\\fftw-3.3.5-dll64")
target_link_directories(${TargetName} PRIVATE "C:\\path\\to\\fftw-3.3.5-dll64")
target_link_libraries(${TargetName} PRIVATE libfftwf3-3)
```

After building this, the application was still not working. Eventually, I figured out that on opening the executable, windows was looking for the libfftw3-3 ***dll*** file. At the time I just wanted to get it working, so I copied the `.dll` files that are included with the library - even though this is shared/dynamic linking, not static linking.

---

I'm now trying to properly statically link the library; I removed the dll's from my build folder and filtered my `CMakeLists.txt` file down to:

```
add_executable(${TargetName} PRIVATE main.cpp)
target_include_directories(${TargetName} PRIVATE "C:\\path\\to\\fftw-3.3.5-dll64")
target_link_libraries(${TargetName} PRIVATE libfftwf3-3)
```

This builds, as I would expect it would. However, even though, in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, I've taken the steps to statically link the library, I'm still required to copy the dll's over in order for the executable to run (its dynamically linking still).

---

(Successful) verbose build output: https://pastebin.com/bbrZdd7r

Comment: Can you show the output of the verbose link command?

Comment: @squareskittles i dont know what you mean

Comment: When you compile the executable, there will be typically be some logs printed. It would be helpful to include these in your question post. What is your compiler? There should be a way to show a more verbose compilation/linkage output so that this log prints additional information that will be helpful to solve the issue.

Comment: @squareskittles MSVC 1926 (using ninja). I'll add the build output (it passes)

Comment: To get the verbose linker output, you might try running `ninja -v` to provide additional verbosity. This will show *which* library is actually being linked.

Comment: @squareskittles I'm building using `cmake -build` not `ninja`

Comment: for some reason, the `cmake -build` only works from my ide's "build" button. There's no option to pass ninja parameters, because it's accessing cmake, not the underlying ninja compiler. Building directly with `ninja` fails. I think environment variables / parameters (like include dirs) are missing when i try to run `ninja` externally

Comment: Ah ok, you can also do `cmake --build . -v` to enable verbose output when compiling the project via the `cmake` command.

Comment: @squareskittles I need to build from a command line in order to build with the -v flag. This command ilne cant build - im assuming due to a lack of enviroment variables. I get errors like `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory` which don't occur in my IDE

Comment: I got it working by using the special MSVC native tools command line (with the environment set up)

Comment: @squareskittles I posted the whole build output

Comment: Thanks, the linker output shows `..\libs\fftw-3.3.5-dll64\libfftw3f-3.lib` being linked, is this the library you intend to link? Static or dynamic?

Comment: @squareskittles Yes, i notiecd that too. That's the correct library I want to link. Yet, when I open the exe, it says it cant find the dll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LIB files you generated from the DEF files are "stubs". They contain just enough code to load the DLL and call functions from it. They do not contain the actual FFTW code. You cannot statically link with these pre-built FFTW LIBs.

You will need to compile FFTW into a static library yourself first. It comes with a [CMake](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) build file where you can turn off `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`.

edit: on review, your question is nearly identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265217/how-to-use-fftw-dll-import-library-lib-as-a-static-lib-in-my-project), with the same answer.

Comment: I appreciate this answer btw, but this isn't correct. That repository you linked is for contributors (it does not contain the whole source - auto-generated C code). The repositories readme makes it extra that most people are not supposed to be using it. What you actually have to do is download the source `.tar.gz` from the website. They then provide bash scripts `BUILD-MINGW32/64.sh` for building on windows (this is the script they use to generate the dlls provided for windows). To use this script, its easiest to install MINGW, with `gcc` and `make`

Comment: I specifically linked to the CMake file (which is cross-platform) to illustrate how to build it. You are indeed supposed to grab the source tarball from their website and can build that using CMake.

Comment: So, you're saying you can interchange the `BUILD-MINGW64.sh` script with this cmake project? That doesn't make sense to me as theyre 2 different sources

Comment: Also, I agree that the question is actually the same as the one you linked. I actually found my answer there yesterday. This one is clearer though.

Comment: If you inspect that script you will see it calls `configure ...; make` three times. CMake was added to FFTW in 2017 as an alternative to calling configure. I don't have a windows machine on hand, but I'm fairly certain that building with CMake is equivalent  to the configure+make approach.

Comment: I'll try downloading the cmake file and adding it to the tarball, and building

Comment: The CMakeLists.txt is already part of the source tarball, I just checked.

Comment: Yeh, I just noticed. That is a huge relief, I can use my standard tools instead of having to hack around with make / mingw / BUILD-MINGWH.sh

Comment: Thanks for this. Yesterday I actually fell asleep after waiting an hour for my build using the bash scripts / mingw - it actually failed when I woke up. using cmake it took a minute.

Comment: Do you know if they have the tarballs available on git, so I can add it as a submodule to my git project

Comment: They probably do not, Git is not supposed to store tarballs. But you could bundle the tarball yourself.

Comment: I was wanting to keep the size of my module small - all my other libs are submodules, which is nice.

Comment: how do I link the library using `target_link_libraries`? Do I add the path to the compiled lib like I did in the question? I cant even find the generated lib

Comment: with another library (including as a sub cmake project as well) I use `project::project_module`. `#include <fftw3.h>` is no longer working either now

Comment: Best to ask a new question showing how you compiled fftw and how you are trying to link it.

Answer (score 0):

`libs` can be either static or dynamic. The one's generated (following the instructions in the `README-WINDOWS` file) are shared (they link to the `.dll` files inside the same folder.

With the windows binaries provided by FFTW, you cannot statically link (because all they provide are the dynamic libraries (`.dll`s). If you look at the file size of the `.lib` file, it's very small, because it's just a reference to the `.dll`s.

Follow the instructions on FFTW's windows page, for building the library from the source. Because you're now building the library yourself, you have the option to turn of "shared-library" and make a "static" lib.